# Developer survey 2015, high rep users OS choice

Tags: support, survey, survey-2015

[The developer survey 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015) and the results were so interesting for me, I even downloaded the [raw data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzd_CzYvUxE5U1NSWnA2SFVKX00/view) and spend some time with it, great information! like this one about OS choice of the survey participants:

[image]

But then there is this `"closer examination of the data"`:

> Upon closer examination of the data, a trend emerges: Developers increasingly prefer spaces as they gain experience. Stack Overflow reputation correlates with a preference for spaces, too: users who have 10,000 rep or more prefer spaces to tabs at a ratio of 3 to 1.

well, it seems there is the information that high rep users prefer `spaces`, ok nice! But is it possible also to get info about what is the high rep users' choice of OS ?

The problem being that **rep info is not included in the raw data**!

Comment: It is the kind of experience they need to realize that pressing the Tab key *actually* inserts spaces.  Takes a while, can be years.

Comment: So if you downloaded the raw data, why aren't you plotting this yourself?

Comment: @Servy, updated `rep info is not included in the raw data`

Comment: All the data say is that people who have more experience *with SO* prefer spaces. It says nothing about their experience programming :P

Comment: It seems quite possible to get lots of rep here answering trivial questions, and hence end up being an "experienced SO user" but still not really an experienced programmer. Not sure I'd assign overly much weight to surveys like this if you're trying to determine best practices.

Comment: A _tab character_ is not the same as a _space character_. Yes, some editors do convert tabs to spaces or simply insert spaces when the tab key is pressed but that doesn't make the two equal. Ask anyone who has had to work with Makefiles.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Experience is measured as a separate statistic from SO reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-experience. Note the word "too" in the quote: the correlation between a preference for spaces and SO rep exists _in addition to_ the correlation between said preference and experience.

Comment: If you guys read the quotation correctly, you'd maybe notice that it doesn't assert that experience and SO reputation correlate. It says that **both** experience and SO reputation correlate with preference for spaces. **How experience was measured wasn't disclosed.**

Comment: @HansPassant And then next tier of experience: realizing that not all IDEs does this, and that the first thing you need to check in your IDE is if replaces tabs with spaces.

Comment: Rep info in the raw data would be too personally identifiable, I think.  Particularly for very high rep users.

Comment: @Wildcard I was just about to say that - I can find the record that corresponds to my answers in the data already. Though you could possibly get round it by having rep banding like 1-1k, 1k-5k, 5k-10k, 10k-50k, 50k-100k, 100k+

Comment: and one of the staff members could take a look and kindly publish the result

Comment: @Lundin *All* IDEs *can* do this. Whether it's the default setting or not is a different matter. Moreover good editors have filetype sensitive indentation, so that when you edit a Makefile it will correctly use tabs instead of spaces to comply with the syntax.

Comment: @Bakuriu I take it you didn't program in Windows during late 90s. Indeed most _modern_ IDEs have the option, but not always per default.

Comment: I reprogrammed emacs to insert a tab every time I hit space 4 times - yes, I'm that good. No-one else thought it was even possible. After that I was able to hack time (https://youtu.be/KEkrWRHCDQU)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan "Ask anyone who has had to work with Makefiles" -- yep, one of my very first times committing/deploying code at my first job I wrecked a Makefile by inserting a space-indented line.

Comment: @bph Thank you for making this dumb thread worthwhile.