# Highlight original poster's comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, accessibility

It would be very helpful to see OP comments highlighted, for being able to detect which comment is based upon the OP's experience with the given suggestions.

Comment: They're already highlighted for the author of a _question_. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Z9E.png). If you mean something else, please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Might be useful: "Unique colour for each user in comments to make following users in long comment threads easier": [CommentUserColours.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentUserColours.user.js)

Comment: I totally missed it. Being one of the lucky (partially) color blind males the background didn't stand out for me. I was thinking more of the full comment being highlighted with a background.

Anyway now that I know what to look for I'm ok.

Comment: @gil_mo you can create a custom highlighting. OP's name in comments is marked with two CSS classes: `class="comment-user owner"`, so if you make a CSS rule `.comment-user.owner { background-color: /* ... */}` you can change what the background colour is in the page so it looks OK for you. You can use the Stylus browser extension (or others) to create a custom userstyle.

Comment: This feature request can still be expanded (in my opinion) to the OPs of answers, at least for the comment section of their own answer...

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 Samuel Liew made a userscript that will colour code repeated commenters in [CommentUserColours](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentUserColours.user.js). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1mpl.png) I'm the only one with more than one comment, so only I get a colour. (Please excuse the confetti, that's another script :-)

Comment: Believe me, you aren't the only one to think it's hard to follow: [Please make comment threads easier to follow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319124/691711)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already posted in the comments, the OP name has a highlighted background.

I totally missed it. Being one of the lucky (partially) color-blind males, the background didn't stand out for me. I was thinking more of the full comment being highlighted with a background. Anyway, now that I know what to look for I'm ok.

Comment: Are you using dark mode or light mode? Does switching between the two help in distinguishing the foreground from the background?

Comment: Dark mode doesn't make a difference, thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand color blindness, it shouldn't affect your ability to discern a tinted background. Even if you can't accurately perceive the color, you should still see a difference in contrast/lightness. I would say this is more likely to be a result of your LCD monitor being poorly calibrated.

Comment: Well I can see it, but it just doesn't stand out like it does for you.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is, I think that's more of an issue with your monitor than with your eyes. I use multiple computers, with multiple screens on each, and on some of the screens, the contrast is very distinctive. On others, it's barely even visible. Tweaking the contrast usually helps to resolve this. (That's much easier on real monitors than it is on laptops with integrated LCDs, but those usually support a software calibration that can resolve these issues.)